# Unable to generate a non-linear model fit to single variable data

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to model the Kerr effect with experimental data, and the relationship between the independent variable voltage applied(U) and light intensity on crossed polarizers (L) is L = a * sin(b*U^2), where a and b are independent constants to be determined.

```
data = {{300, 0.014336918}, {350, 0.023297491}, {400, 
   0.053763441}, {450, 0.098566308}, {500, 0.172043011}, {550, 
   0.23297491}, {600, 0.336917563}, {650, 0.336917563}, {700, 
   0.403225806}, {750, 0.448028674}, {800, 0.480286738}, {850, 
   0.485663082}, {900, 0.487455197}, {950, 0.476702509}, {970, 
   0.465949821}, {985, 0.435483871}, {995, 0.415770609}}

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*Sin (b*(x^2)), {a, b}, x]
```

However, I get the following error:

```
NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: ...
 is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {17} at {a,b} = {1.,1.}.
```

I'm new to programming in this language but I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Is there any way to structure my data so that this function actually works?

Comment: `Sin (b*(x^2))` is not Mathematica syntax...use `Sin[b*(x^2)]`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the documentation, I realize that the non-linear function is a local iterated approximation method and since the coefficient of the parameter b is too small, Mathematica is unable to compute the value of b. Thus linearisation of the function and substitution back into the original equation solved my problem.